# The word ''Bibliography'' with lowercase letters

Tags: header-footer, capitalization

I'm writing my report in mathematics with the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Useful Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------------------math---------------------------------------
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath} % new extention de amsmath  
%---------------------divers---------------------------------------
\usepackage{pifont} %ding
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\VerbatimFootnotes % allows verbatim text in footnotes
%-------------------------hyperref------------------------------

\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red , linkcolor= blue}

%------------       
%--------------------------accent-------------------------          
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%-------réduire le mot reference----------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section}{\subsection}{}{}
%------
%------minimiser l'espace entre les reference----
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@openbib@code{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
\makeatother
%-----------------  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Style des titres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
%---- Dimensions des marges --------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%---------------------écriture foncé-----------
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % pour avoir une écriture bien foncée
%\usepackage{helvet}
%----------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{examples}{Examples}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%-----------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\let\origproofname\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\upshape\bfseries\origproofname}

\newenvironment{dem}{{\noindent {\bf Sketch of Proof.}}}{\hfill {\rule{2mm}{2mm}}}

\newenvironment{pr}{{\noindent {\bf Second Proof of}}}{\hfill {\rule{3mm}{3mm}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-----------------------------head and foot--------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % supprime les en-têtes et pieds pr\'ed\'efinis
\fancyhead[L,R]{\bfseries\thepage}% Left Even, Right Odd
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\rightmark} % Left Odd
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\leftmark} % Right Even
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{ }} %ici ecrire cooperate

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.pt}% filet en haut de page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.pt}% filet en bas de page

\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
\newpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}}
\rhead{\textbf{\thepage}} %{\textsl{\rightmark}}
\lhead{\textsl{\leftmark}}%{\textbf{\thepage}}
\lfoot{\footnotesize{\textbf{}}}  % titre de la these
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-------Chapter style-------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\Huge\scshape\bfseries}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XcX@{}}\titlerule[5pt]& \large\mdseries\raisebox{-1.05ex}{\chaptername\enspace\arabic{chapter}} & \titlerule[5pt]\end{tabularx}}{-1ex}{\hrule\vspace{1ex} }[\vspace{0.75ex}\endgraf\hrule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-8ex}{20ex}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]{\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}%
{\titlerule[5pt]}{-2.2ex}{\hrule\vspace{1.5ex}}[\vspace{0.75ex}\endgraf\hrule]

%-----------This chapter contains--------------
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-------------------------
%\pagestyle{plain} % les numérotations en pieds de page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\begin{document}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\newpage
 Let consider
\begin{thebibliography}{999} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\footnotesize
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%-A-%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibitem{axlupol}{O. Axelsson, H. Lu, B. Polman,} {On the numerical radius of matrices and its application to iterative solution methods,} Linear Multilinear Algebra 37 (1994) 225-238. 

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Afer compilation I get the word ''Bibliography'' in uppercase letters.

[image]

I want to get the word ''Bibliography'' in lowercase letters.

Comment: Do you want it in tiny font or in lowercase letters?

Comment: Please see my edit. You will see the the only problem appear in the chapter bibliography. Thank you for your help.

Comment: After compilation the chapter 1 appears in the head ''Chapter one'' i.e. with tiny letter

Comment: I won't see that because your not-very-minimal example does not have a chapter one. Anyway `\nouppercase` won't hurt a chapter title that is already lowercase

Comment: Can I change to word bibliography by references? Thank you very much

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the header lowercase by adding `\nouppercase` to your definition of the left header.

Also if you look into the warnings produced by your document, it will tell you that the `\headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 14.49998pt.`

My personal opinion: I find it highly unusual to have the chapter name on the left and the page number on the right site of a verso page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{\textbf{\thepage}}
\lhead{\textsl{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}%
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{thebibliography}{999} 
\newpage
\bibitem{axlupol}{O. Axelsson, H. Lu, B. Polman,} {On the numerical radius of matrices and its application to iterative solution methods,} Linear Multilinear Algebra 37 (1994) 225-238. 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Full code from the question:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Useful Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------------------math---------------------------------------
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath} % new extention de amsmath  
%---------------------divers---------------------------------------
\usepackage{pifont} %ding
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\VerbatimFootnotes % allows verbatim text in footnotes
%-------------------------hyperref------------------------------

\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red , linkcolor= blue}

%------------       
%--------------------------accent-------------------------          
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%-------réduire le mot reference----------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section}{\subsection}{}{}
%------
%------minimiser l'espace entre les reference----
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@openbib@code{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
\makeatother
%-----------------  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Style des titres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
%---- Dimensions des marges --------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%---------------------écriture foncé-----------
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % pour avoir une écriture bien foncée
%\usepackage{helvet}
%----------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{examples}{Examples}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%-----------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\let\origproofname\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\upshape\bfseries\origproofname}

\newenvironment{dem}{{\noindent {\bf Sketch of Proof.}}}{\hfill {\rule{2mm}{2mm}}}

\newenvironment{pr}{{\noindent {\bf Second Proof of}}}{\hfill {\rule{3mm}{3mm}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-----------------------------head and foot--------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % supprime les en-têtes et pieds pr\'ed\'efinis
\fancyhead[L,R]{\bfseries\thepage}% Left Even, Right Odd
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\rightmark} % Left Odd
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\leftmark} % Right Even
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{ }} %ici ecrire cooperate

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.pt}% filet en haut de page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.pt}% filet en bas de page

\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
\newpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}}
\rhead{\textbf{\thepage}} %{\textsl{\rightmark}}
\lhead{\textsl{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}%{\textbf{\thepage}}
\lfoot{\footnotesize{\textbf{}}}  % titre de la these
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-------Chapter style-------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\Huge\scshape\bfseries}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XcX@{}}\titlerule[5pt]& \large\mdseries\raisebox{-1.05ex}{\chaptername\enspace\arabic{chapter}} & \titlerule[5pt]\end{tabularx}}{-1ex}{\hrule\vspace{1ex} }[\vspace{0.75ex}\endgraf\hrule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-8ex}{20ex}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]{\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}%
{\titlerule[5pt]}{-2.2ex}{\hrule\vspace{1.5ex}}[\vspace{0.75ex}\endgraf\hrule]

%-----------This chapter contains--------------
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-------------------------
%\pagestyle{plain} % les numérotations en pieds de page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\begin{document}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\newpage
 Let consider
\begin{thebibliography}{999} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\footnotesize
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%-A-%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibitem{axlupol}{O. Axelsson, H. Lu, B. Polman,} {On the numerical radius of matrices and its application to iterative solution methods,} Linear Multilinear Algebra 37 (1994) 225-238. 

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. Please compile my codes you will see in the head of page 2 the word Bibliography in capital

Comment: @Student Do you want it in capital or not?

Comment: Now it is good but I don't understand what is the modification in my code?. By the way why you think that  it highly unusual to have the chapter name on the left and the page number on the right site of a verso page? I think it is beauty

Comment: @Student You need to add `\nouppercase{}` to the definition of the left header. I find this arrangement strange because page numbers are normally on the outside of the page, which would be on the left of a verso page.

Comment: I hope that you add the necessary modifications in my codes in order to get a very good work. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Student Just replace the line `\lhead{\textsl{\leftmark}}%{\textbf{\thepage}}` from your code with `\lhead{\textsl{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}%`

Comment: When I replace the line \lhead{\textsl{\leftmark}}%{\textbf{\thepage}} from my code with \lhead{\textsl{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}%, I obtain the word  Reference in the place of the word Bibliography and with a very small size

Comment: @Student Are you sure that you don't have have the code from the other answer in your document?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand very well your question. You have written ''Also if you look into the warnings produced by your document, it will tell you that the \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 14.49998pt.'' How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot for your great help.

Comment: @Student Well, do you have `\markboth{\tiny Reference}` in your code? This would explain why the name magically changed.

Comment: @Student In my very very short first code block there is exactly one line which contains the word headheight, use this line in your code.

Comment: Yes I delete `\markboth{\tiny Reference}` and it compiles correctly. Please my last question. My goal is to obtain a very good and beauty thesis. I will be very very greatful if you help me to improve my codes. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @Student To ask for a review of your code is way too broad for this site, maybe try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I remark also that you add `\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}`. Is this a way to correct this problem `\headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 14.49998pt`?.

Comment: @Student Does the warning go away if you do?

Comment: No  the  warning is the  same.

Comment: @Student That shouldn't be the case

Comment: It is written `Overfull \hbox (21.12332pt too wide) detected at line 2098`.

Comment: @Student That is an entirely different warning. is the warning about the headheight still there?

Comment: No the warning about headheight is not there. Thanks a lot for fixing the problem.